# How to get Feedjira to follow redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, feedjira

I am using Feedjira's fetch_and_parse method to parse RSS feeds in my app, but some RSS feeds that I feed it are feed URLS that redirect to another feed URL, and Feedjira doesn't follow these redirects and my fetch_and_parse fails. Is there a way to get Feedjira to follow RSS redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem, and solved it by manually fetching feeds (using Faraday) and calling `FeedJira::Feed.parse` with the resulting XML:

```
def fetch(host, url)
  conn = Faraday.new(:url => host) do |faraday|
    faraday.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects, limit: 3
  end

  response = conn.get url
  return response.body
end

xml = fetch("http://www.npr.org", "/templates/rss/podcast.php?id=510298")
podcast = Feedjira::Feed.parse(xml)
```

You could also monkey-patch Feedjira's `connection` method to do the same thing, though I wouldn't recommend it:

```
module Feedjira
  class Feed
    def self.connection(url)
      Faraday.new(url: url) do |conn|
        conn.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects, limit: 3
      end
    end
  end
end

podcast = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://www.npr.org/templates/rss/podcast.php?id=510298")
```

Comment: This is how I ended up solving this problem a long time ago. Thanks for the answer! I forgot to update this question with it.